# Assigning an implicitly unwrapped optional to an explicit optional

Tags: swift, option-type

If a function returns an implicitly unwrapped optional, would you ever assign it to a explicit optional?

For example, in Chris Adamson's [blog post](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2014/06/14/swift-and-the-last-mile/), he first lists a function that return an implicitly unwrapped, and later he assigns the return value of the function to an explicit optional.

```
class func JSONObjectWithData(_ data: NSData!,
                      options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions,
                        error error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject!

let jsonResponse : AnyObject? =
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(evilData,
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0),
    error: &parseError);
```

If the function is going to return something that cannot be nil, why assign it to an optional?

Comment: In the current (beta 6) SDK, JSONObjectWithData() returns `AnyObject?`.

Comment: Thanks Martin R, I am aware of that - wanted to use Chris's example to find out why he assigned an implicit to an explicit.

Comment: The section in the beta 6 release notes starting with *"A large number of Foundation APIs have been audited for optional conformance ..."* is also interesting in this context.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, the return of `AnyObject!` is a bug in the SDK (technically it's just a place that they've used the auto-Swiftifier and haven't hand-fixed it yet). `JSONObjectWithData` absolutely can return `nil`. From the docs:

> Return Value:
>   A Foundation object from the JSON data in data, or nil if an error occurs.

Chris is rescuing this value from a possible crash by moving it to an explicit optional rather than an implicit one that actually could be ni.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  So in normal condition, if a function is declared correctly, you should never have to assign an implicitly unwrapped optional to an explicit, correct?

Comment: Rob, "the return of `AnyObject!` is a bug ... [because this method] absolutely can return `nil`." While it may be a better design to return `AnyObject?`, I'm not sure I'd characterize this as a "bug". `AnyObject!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional and, as such, can be `nil` (in fact, it only makes sense in the context where the return value _could_ be `nil`). So the fact that the return value could be `nil` is not incompatible with the `AnyObject!` return type. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point...

Comment: @Rob It's technically a bug, but you can think of it as a kind of default holding position while all the existing SDK methods get some Swififying love, as Rob says. For *Swift*, the correct return type here would be a real Optional, so the caller gets the hint that what comes back may well be nil. You can't really tell from an implicitly-unwrapped Optional return from an SDK method whether the value could ever be nil or not, so in this case an explicit Optional is better "documentation", if you like.

Comment: @MattGibson I agree that they should remove the ambiguity and I'm glad they're doing that. I was just quibbling over the "bug" terminology, which might lead future readers to conclude that the implicitly unwrapped optional wouldn't work here. It works fine, but you just check that it's not `nil` before using it any context where it would be implicitly unwrapped (much like you do with an optional binding or forced unwrapping of a standard optional). But I completely agree that this implicitly-unwrapped optional is more ambiguous than needed and welcome the clean up of the API.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use this approach whenever you can change an `Implicit Unwrapped Optional` to an `Optional Type` returned by api as also xcode future releases will try to replace their api's from `Implicit Optionals type` to `explicit optional` and in beta 6 and 5 this approach has started and many api's has been changed to use `explicit optional` type.The expert advice is to avoid the `Implicit Unwrapped Optional` whenever possible because you will get crash whenever a `nil` is unwrapped automatically.While using `optional(explicit)` type you have to explicitly unwrap the value so you do this by putting a `if` condition or if you really sure it will not nil than you can unwrap it without `if`(but you should always check for `nil` case).

`JSONObjectWithData` can return `nil` as you do not know what is in `evilData` and if it is not able to convert in `json` you will get the `nil` value and if you try to use `jsonResponse` with `implicit optional type` in elsewhere in code than your app will crash at runtime.That's why chris has used `explicit optional` to take care this case and in else where use of `jsonResponse` will not unwrap automatically to nil which can leads to crashes.If you unwrapping the code yourself with `if` or `optional binding` you  can avoid crash and show some meaning full message.

Comment: (Stylistic note: The back ticks "``" are for `code`, not for general emphasis. Marking `every important phrase` with `back ticks` does not `improve` the `legibility`. There are other markup methods like *italics* or **bold face** :)

Answer (score -1):

An implicitly unwrapped optional is still an optional, although it's guaranteed to hold a value.

Assigning an implicitly unwrapped optional to a normal optional is legit.

So if you have a linear logic in your app where you declare an optional variable and then initialize it with an implicitly unwrapped optional, it would be better to use a non-optional.

But there are some cases where you define an optional variable (let's say at the beginning of a function), and then basing on conditions, flow, if etc. it can be assigned a value from different functions - if at least one of them can return a normal optional, then you have to declare the variable as optional.

But in that case, even if all functions used to assign a value to your optional/non-optional variable always return either a non optional or (at least one of them) an implicitly unwrapped optional, it's always better to stick with the optional declaration, because in the future you may a new branch of code that returns a normal optional.

Last, very interestingly, **this seems to work fine**:

```
let x: Int! = nil
```

whereas I have to admit **I expected it to throw a runtime exception**. Knowing that, I think from now on I'll always use an optional when a function claims to return an implicitly unwrapped.

More testing:

```
func test() -> Int! {
    return nil
}

let q1: Int? = test() // it works, q1 = nil (expected)
let q2: Int! = test() // it works, q2 = nil (unexpected)
let q3: Int = test() // runtime exception (expected)
```

**Update**: This is what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_491) says instead:

> If you try to access an implicitly unwrapped optional when it does not contain a value, you will trigger a runtime error. The result is exactly the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal optional that does not contain a value.

Which means: assigning `nil` is ok, but as soon as it is accessed (i.e. assigned to another variable, used in an expression, etc.) it will trigger the error

Comment: Why did you expect assigning nil to an implicitly-unwrapped Optional value to throw a runtime exception? It's every bit as valid as assigning nil to a normal Optional. The ! only means that you don't have to unwrap it manually when you access it; it could still hold a nil value.

Comment: @MattGibson: I just didn't realize it throws the error only when it is accessed (see updated answer at bottom of my answer). It makes sense because under the hood it's still an optional, so assigning nil is legit.